# How to use mount and QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy in wicket 6.x or 7.x

Tags: wicket, wicket-1.5, wicket-6, wicket-1.6, wicket-7

I have code as shown below,

```
mount(new QueryStringUrlCodingStrategy(pwdRstHomeURl.substring(pwdRstHomeURl.lastIndexOf('/')), UserHome.class));
```

How can I modify this code into 6.x or 7.x?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `mountPage` wicket 1.5 onwards.

```
mountPage(pwdRstHomeURl.substring(pwdRstHomeURl.lastIndexOf('/'), UserHome.class);
```

For more information take a look at [this page](https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/6.x/guide/urls.html#urls_6)